# How to identify a custom UIWebView like in FlipBoard or MobileRss

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

How can I identify if an application is using a custom `UIWebView`?

For instance in this case:

[image]

Can someone suggest me how this can be done?

Comment: What's 'custom' in the WebView? Isn't it the content, more than the container, that matters?

Comment: Is the grammar in that right? I'm confused on whether Edwin is an organization or a person.

Comment: custom because I think they used a UIWebView to do a preview of the post... so with the css they can make it nice and more easy to manage.... without go crazy with UILabel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "custom", you mean sub-classing UIWebView, nothing you described in your requirements calls for doing that.  Instead, a combination of HTML/CSS/Javascript executed within the UIWebView, plus any necessary UIKit controls positioned around the UIWebView, should give you everything you need.